# Start Menu, Cortana & taskbar not working in Win10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, start-menu

I upgraded a user from Windows 7 Pro to Windows 10 (in place upgrade) and his Start Menu does not work. I created two new local profiles, disjointed from the domain but still, the Start Menu does not work under any profile.

I downloaded and ran the Win10 Start Menu troubleshooter from MS (startmenu.diagcab) and it returned this:
***"Required applications are not installed correctly. 
"Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost" and "Microsoft.Windows.Cortana" applications need to be installed correctly."***

One would think that these PowerShell commands would resolve the issue, but for whatever reason, they do not:

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.Cortana | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

I found [another SU post on this exact issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1123371/windows-10-start-up-menu-how-to-reinstall-shellexperiencehost-cortana), but none of the suggested solutions have worked. As a temporary workaround, I have installed [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) for the user, but this might not be acceptable for him since the taskbar is still broken (right-click doesn't work in the taskbar).

What are my options here, a repair-install? Thank you for your time.

**Final update:** I ended up rolling the user back to Win7 via VEEAM EP backup, updating all drivers, BIOS and Windows, then reattempting the Win10 upgrade and it worked as expected.

Comment: had the same problem, created a new user and this user was ok for me. But it seems you already did this. So repair or even a clean install would be the solution :/

Comment: Does other metro apps work well? Does this problem arise automatically? Or after some tweaking?

Comment: No metro apps work, to my knowledge (I will double-check this). The issue started as soon as the Win10 upgrade from Win7 was done. The end user finished the upgrade process, so I did not see it. My assumption now is that it had some failure he didn't tell me about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are core packages provided by Windows 10. Since they weren't installed on upgrade, it's plausible that the installation corrupted. Maybe these missing packages are just the beginning of your nightmare.

When Windows is installed all current features and packages are copied to the installation. They're then enabled based on configuration, including what level of Windows you're running (Home vs Pro). If those powershell commands are failing, it's pointing towards the installation having not copied over all the files.

Ideally the best solution would be to wipe and install Windows 10 fresh. Alternatively you could see if a restore point was made, there usually is, and restore Windows 7 and re-attempt the upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, @zzarzzur. I have a full-disk backup of the Win7 OS that I took via VEEAM endpoint backup. I can rollback to it, but is there no hope for a "repair install" with Windows 10 install media?

Comment: @KidACrimson You can try using a Windows 10 installation disk and using "repair my computer" and running the troubleshooter. Options such as "Refresh my PC" rely on the copied features, which seem to be corrupted.

Comment: I ended up rolling the user back to Win7 via VEEAM EP backup, updating all drivers, BIOS and Windows, then reattempting the Win10 upgrade and it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem (Start menu and Search, Notifications, etc. panels does not work) after a system update. OS version is "Windows 10 Pro 1890 OS build 17763.55 (dev. preview)"

Here is short instruction from [this article](http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/computing/windows-10/has-your-windows-10-start-menu-stopped-working-here-are-four-ways-to-fix-it-11364000314532) that helped me:

1. Launch powershell: Win+R, type `powershell`, Enter
2. In powershell type: `Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs`, Enter to start another powershell with admin privileges.
3. In the admin powershell type: `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}` to reinstall win10 apps (like Calendar, Alarms, etc...)
4. Restart. Ctrl+Alt+Del, Power button in the left-down corner.

You can also check your system for integrity,  in the admin powershell type: `sfc /scannow`. See more details in the article I mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

If you are still stuck try this simplest of the solution.

Press Win + R (to open Run )
copy paste and press enter to run this program. "C:\Windows\system32\ctfmon.exe". it brings back the language bar and for me it allowed me to type in windows search, start menu and WINDOWS 10 apps again
I think it is due to missing Language bar or some think like that